# Dynamic, temporary variables with property groups

Tags: python

I don't know the correct terms for these types of variables, so **dynamic/temporary** may not be the best name for them. But while conducting tests with Blender class instances and comparing behavior to normal Python class instances, I've noticed that there is something different about the way Blender property group instances (variables) work.

Using normal Python variables/instances, I can do something crazy like this, where `NotDefined` is not defined in `MYCLASS`:

```
a = MYCLASS()
b = a
b.NotDefined = "stuff"
c = a
```

Now `NotDefined == "stuff"` in all variables (`a`, `b`, and `c`).

This next bit is using `propgroup`, which is a class instance derived from `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` and attached with `bpy.props.PointerProperty`:

```
a = scene_object.propgroup
b = a
c = scene_object.propgroup
b.NotDefined = "stuff"
d = scene_object.propgroup
```

In this situation, `NotDefined` will exist in both `a` and `b`, but not `c` or `d`. As someone new to Python/Blender, this situation has thrown me into a cycle of confusion more times than I can count. I just didn't realize it was happening until recent excessive testing.

It's almost as if the property group instance itself is not really an instance, but some kind of instance generator.

Is it at all possible to attach temporary dynamic variables to Blender class instances like property groups? This is more for knowledge, rather than any practical need for them. I know I can attach permanent dynamic properties using `group["name"]=*`. But I'm wondering why the above types of variables don't work in this situation like they do elsewhere, or if there is a way to make them work.

Edit: One other question I had is the impact of this type of problem when trying to define self-variables for instances like operators inside of their constructors? Are we limited to using properties? For example, would it be possible to define a link/ref to an arbitrary non-property class instance (`self.SomeData = other_module.linked_list`)?

Comment: Suggest that internally,  a property akin to the old fashioned `Foo.bar = property(setter, getter)` is how `bpy.props` sets things up, hence `c` in your second example is a different instance of the value returned from the property's get method and in no way related to `a or b`.  To avoid confusion class instancing is rarely used in blender eg `ob = bpy.types.Object(...)` is not used, rather `ob = bpy.data.objects.new(...)`    We don't instance a property-group, rather register it and assign to a pointer or collection prop.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have a habit of using temporary references to work with scene data, so I've never directly dealt with property groups - just other variables linked to them. So it always looked like `group.Prop = 10` worked. But then when I would send the property group to a function and have that function make changes, those changes would not be there when it came back. Took me a while to narrow it down to this problem.